# Excel - plotting - Dynamic rows & columns (using Name Manager/Formulas)

Tags: excel, plot, dynamic, excel-formula

My Excel tab is populated with data from an external source where number of rows are dynamic, and so are **number of columns**. E.g. let us say rows can be from 2 to 15, and columns can be from B to D.

| Date | MSFT | AMZN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/31/2021 | 0.11 | 1.2 |
| 2/28/2021 | 0.15 | 0.5 |
| 3/31/2021 | 0.05 | 0.8 |
| 4/30/2021 | 0.06 | 0.3 |
| 5/31/2021 | 0.2 | 0.6 |
| 6/30/2021 | 0.34 | 0.2 |
| 7/31/2021 | 0.3 | 0.8 |
| ......... | ..... | .... |
| ......... | ..... | .... |

Plotting dynamic rows in Excel is easy. One can use `OFFSET` as shown below. My problem is with dynamic columns. Here column D is empty. What if I suddenly have GOOG values in column D? I used `Name Managers` to plot the chart. But I am unable to make the columns dynamic.

```
Date:   OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$15))
Ticker1:OFFSET(Sheet1!$B$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$15))
Ticker2:OFFSET(Sheet1!$C$2,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$15))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### ♣ SOLVED ♣

I have addressed the following query alone: *"I am unable to make columns dynamic":*

See Google Sheet (link below) which features dynamic rows and columns for arbitrary data.  You didn't share a workbook, so I made up my own data - you'll have to customise the functions to your liking.

---

**Link**

[Google Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QwVCLHeNdct9xfIPGDLg8n6VESfYbXnCfjQQ9DKPtCE/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**Functionality within Excel:**

[image: Depiction of dynamic rows & column in Excel]

---

**Function**

(in relation to above screenshot [cell H3]):

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(INDEX($A$3:OFFSET($A$2,COUNTA(A:A)-1,COUNTA($2:$2)-1,1,1),0,MATCH(G3,$2:$2,0))),"")
```

---

**Depiction of Google Sheets**

[image: Google Sheets presentation: dynamic columns]

---

**Notes**

- Excel and Google sheet functions vary slightly - one common example concerns application of array functionality - whereas in Sheets you need to press 'ctrl + shift + enter' (Office 365, you just enter the function in a single cell, press enter and voila!)
- Note - this is the general method/technique for creating dynamic range (often, the dynamic range function itself is placed in 'Formula/Name Ranges' - such functions are generally flawed in that they require adequate 'empty' cells beneath (dynamic rows) or the right (e.g. dynamic columns).
- I've expanded on that in one of my previous solutions, but you can
  find plenty of material on this topic e.g. just google 'dynamic range
  excel' and take any of the top 3 results, which, at time if writing,
  had the following: (a) [Excel-easy.com](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html); (b) [Excel-Jet](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html)
  (c) [Yet another Excel-Jet](https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-named-range-with-index)

---